# 2 routers, 2 DNS - 1 internet connection, 1 home network

Tags: networking, router, home-networking

My home network consists of a DSL modem/router provided by my ISP and a second TP-Link router (currently functioning as a switch / Wi-Fi access point)  in another room (media room). I am using an Apple TV, which allows me to change its DNS settings so I can watch USA Netflix from abroad.

I recently ordered an HDMI Roku Stick because it has certain features that Apple TV doesn't. The problem: You can't change the DNS settings on the Roku, you have to do it at router level, and my ISP will not give me the password to my main router, so I can't change the DNS there.

The Roku will be connected to the media room router, but changing the DNS on that router didn't seem to have any effect, probably because it is functioning as a switch (DHCP Server is disabled).

So I need a way to use that second (media room) router to provide the DNS for whatever is connected to it, while at the same time sharing the same internet connection (from the ISP router) and also having all my devices to continue to "see" each other (for DLNA, file transfers etc) regardless to what router they are connected to!

Any networking expert that could help?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the Roku lease the IP address(es) of the DNS server(s) through DHCP?  Or does it always use the default gateway IP as its DNS server?

Comment: Apparently with the last update it uses Google's DNS (8.8.8.8) but there is a way to overwrite this with the router: https://support.unlocator.com/customer/portal/articles/1524376-how-to-bypass-forced-dns-on-roku. My problem is that I don't have access to the router of my ISP, and currently the other router is acting as a switch. What I need is to have both routers acting as routers, while at the same time sharing the same internet connection and be able to have all my devices "see" each other as if they were on the same network.

Comment: Does your ISP give the option of turn their DSL router into a bridge so you can use your own router?  Or will they at least let you disable DHCP on their router so you can use a 3rd party DHCP server?

Comment: I would suggest quarantining the router you can't control and using it only to provide Internet access to the router you can control. Connect all devices to the router you can control.

Comment: So far the ISP didn't cooperate in making any changes to their router. They told me to just add my own router after theirs. How would can I "quarantine" the router I can't control? Just do what my ISP suggests, or does it involve something more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [link](https://support.unlocator.com/customer/portal/articles/1524376-how-to-bypass-forced-dns-on-roku) you posted, they are giving instructions to route 8.8.8.8 to nowhere which apparently forces the Roku to use whatever DHCP servers are in the DHCP scope.   Based on what your ISP will allow you to do, here are your options.

1. If your ISP can configure the DSL modem as a bridge instead of a NAT/Router, you can use your own router instead.   Then you can set up routing statements and DHCP as required.
2. If not, see if your ISP will set up the custom route and DNS servers in the DSL modem per your link.
3. If they won't change anything, your last resort is to put another router between their DSL modem and your network.  This will allow you to do the custom route and DHCP settings, at the cost of being [double natted](http://www.practicallynetworked.com/networking/fixing_double_nat.htm).

Comment: Thanks. Double NAT seems the only option from those three. I have a spare router that I could use for that purpose. I was hoping there would be a more "clean" solution that I could avoid adding another router and the possible issues of double NAT on my whole network. Is there no way to use that second router in the media room to get what I want without the need to add a 3rd router? (I wouldn't mind the possible double NAT issues if they were confined in the media room)